# How to change the image while sharing the content to the social networks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am sharing a blog to social networks and while sharing it's picking the random images instead of actual image.
Sharing URL's that i am using are:

```html
<div class="share-bar-link icon-share-facebook" data-share-href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URL_TO_SHARE?cid=share_fb"></div>
```

For example, in the below image (I want to share that blog to any social networking site)
[image: picture1]

But it's taking the image as (Wrong picture is being taken)
[image: picture2]

Comment: RTD: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#markup

Answer (score -1):

To do this you must have access to code of your blog post. In head section there are meta tags which define the way you share something on different sites. It is called OG tags and can also be done through some extensions
Here is simple example of meta tag changing.

`<meta property=“og:image” content=“http://example.com/example.jpg” />`

`<meta property="og:image:width” content="180" />`

`<meta property="og:image:height” content="110" />`

For more information visit this link

https://yourblogworks.com/social-share-image/

Comment: Wrong quotes used in every single one of those examples …

Comment: was giving a general example, but thanks for pointing it out

Comment: General working of code is explained in the website link but you would have to change image every-time you are sharing different blog